# Is there a HTML to MediaWiki Converter?

Tags: html, mediawiki

I've been looking for a while and I can't seem to find a HTML to MediaWiki Converter.

I'm looking for somewhere where I can type something like:

```
HTML Code:
<a href="https://mediawiki.org">MediaWiki</a>
```

and I get:

```
MediaWiki Code:
[https://mediawiki.org MediaWiki]
```

or you type MediaWiki code and get HTML code

Like this:

```
MediaWiki Code:
[https://mediawiki.org MediaWiki]
```

and I get:

```
HTML Code:
<a href="https://mediawiki.org">MediaWiki</a>
```

Comment: Original post: {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116203/is-there-a-html-to-mediawiki-converter}

I got told to ask the question here.

Comment: Welcome!  What OS?  Or are you looking for a web-app?

Comment: I just need a simple website or something. Kind of like Google Translate, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert between html & MediaWiki *(in both directions)* with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html). There are a lot of other possible conversions available to list available input formats run `pandoc --list-input-formats` for output formats `pandoc --list-output-formats` and if course for help use `pandoc --help | more`.

- Free, gratis & Open Source.
- Command line
- Cross Platform
- Normally used with one, or more, input files (or URLs) and an output file specified with the -o flag.
- Can be used interactively by just using the command `pandoc -f input_format -t output_format` and typing or pasting in the text but will only output the results when control-C is pressed to exit.

[image: Command Line Example]

Latest release, bug tracker & source are all available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases)

*Note that recent versions of pandoc, when used from the command line as above, allow multi-line text entry so when you have finished typing you need to press control-Z then enter or control-C for the processing to take place.*

Comment: Doesn't seem to always convert correctly. I'm using gamepedia (which used mediawiki). Not sure if this info is useful but I hope helps somehow

Comment: It may be because it hasn't been updated in two years? Oh, I'm also using http://pandoc.org/try/

Comment: @TigerYT - It would be helpful to know __what__ it doesn't convert properly ideally as a ticket on https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/

Comment: Last release was 2.2.1 on 11th May 2018 at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases - it might be the web site that is behind the times :-)

Comment: Yes, must be. though https://devotter.com/converter worked perfectly (Uses Pandoc)

Comment: Pandoc doesn't work for this!

Comment: @Quidam - which version of pandoc and what is the ___this___ that pandoc doesn't work for?

Comment: (Unless I didn't get what it's supposed to render): I've used several online editors said to be based on Pandoc. None worked. For instance this one: https://pandoc.org/try I paste a HTML snippet with "<p class=...etc>, bold fonts, links, etc,  and I get no formatting, nothing except the plain text.

Comment: When I go to https://pandoc.org/try/ and select from html to mediawikii and type `<p class='Fred'>The <b>Quick</b> brown <i>fox</i> jumps over the <b><i>lazy</i>`</b> dog!</p> I get `The '''Quick''' brown ''fox'' jumps over the '''''lazy''''' dog!` as can be seen at [https://pandoc.org/try/?text=<p+class%3D%27Fred%27>The+<b>Quick<%2Fb>+brown+<i>fox<%2Fi>+jumps+over+the+<b><i>lazy<%2Fi><%2Fb>+dog!<%2Fp>&from=html&to=mediawiki

Comment: @SteveBarnes | Try using `https://devotter.com/converter` it worked for me last time. You'll just have to type the code into a local file and send that to be converted rather than just typing it straight onto the website.

Comment: @Quidam | Check the comment above ^^. It may not work for you, I'm not guaranteeing it but it worked for me last time so there's a 50/50 chance.

Comment: Big thanks for the mention! I really appreciate it. I saw this page, it requires a file as an output, not exactly what I wanted, I wanted direct cut/past of small parts, but I'll give a try.